# Trying simplify checking if object key is true and pushing it to another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm building a form to interact with a remote API by building a GET request query string based on what checkboxes the user selects.

My initial thought was to do a laundry list of if/else checks to see if the model object key is true or not and then make a clean array out of just the object key names. However, would there be a more automated way to do it?

I was thinking something along the lines of an angular.foreach, but I can't figure out how to get the object key names to come out as a value.

For example:

```
function submit() {
  var pushData = [];
  angular.foreach(vm.export, function(item, index){
    if (item == true) {
      pushData[item];
    }
  })
}
```

Here is the object it's pulling from:

```
vm.export = {
  'servers': true,
  'apps': false,
  'users': true,
  'userID': 1234
}
```

How can I push the key names with TRUE values to the **pushData** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach has an item (the object/primitive in the array) and a key.
so your pushData is getting a key called "true"(the value of item) instead of the name(the key).

```
var pushData = [];
angular.foreach(vm.export, function(item, key){
if (item === true) {
    pushData[key];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a for in loop?

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/jazokaw/1/edit?js,console)

```
function submit(){
  var pushData = [];
  for (var prop in data) {
    if (data[prop] === true) {
      pushData.push(prop);
    }
  }
  return pushData;
}
```